# Racket using lambda instead of 2 functions

Tags: lambda, racket, primes

I want to make a program that finds out if a number is prime or not.

First I made this function that works but requires the user to insert 2 as the second argument:

```
(define (prim? number counter)
  (if (>= counter number)
      #t
      (if (= (modulo number counter) 0)
          #f
          (prim? number (+ counter 1)))))
```

So I wanted the user the be able to use the function by using only the necessary information, the number he wants to test. This was the solution:

```
(define (is-prime? number)
  (prim? number 2))

(define (prim? number counter)
  (if (>= counter number)
      #t
      (if (= (modulo number counter) 0)
          #f
          (prim? number (+ counter 1)))))
```

My question then was, how can I rewrite the code by using lambdas and having only one elegant function? So I wrote this:

```
(define (prim number)
   (lambda(counter) (set! counter 2)   
     (if (>= counter number)
         #t
         (if (= (modulo number counter) 0)
             #f
             ((lambda(x) (set! counter (+ counter 1)))
              (prim number))))))
```

When I run `(prim 5)` in the REPL it gives me the message `#<procedure:D:/Racket/prim.rkt:5:2>` and not if the number is prime or not.

How could I write the function with lambdas?

Comment: I guess that you don't want to "use a `lambda`", what you want is to define an inner helper procedure with additional parameters, use a named `let` for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using a named `let` and a `cond` would be more elegant, and you should avoid using `set!` at all costs. Try this:

```
(define (is-prime? number)
  (let prim? ((number number) (counter 2))
    (cond ((>= counter number) #t)
          ((= (modulo number counter) 0) #f)
          (else (prim? number (+ counter 1))))))
```

The above defines an inner helper function called `prim?`. That's simpler than defining a "`lambda`" as you suggested.